# Rails: Omniauth: Github provider doesn't quite work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, github, github-api

I recently forked https://github.com/fortuity/rails3-mongoid-omniauth and tried to get login working for different providers. It works for Twitter and Facebook (You can try it out at http://jgodse-omniauth-mongoid.heroku.com/), but I couldn't get it working for Github. The code snapshot is [here at github](https://github.com/jgodse/rails3-mongoid-omniauth/tree/bc52912411b9674b0f0efe1615dbaf7ecc02a000).

My environment looks like this:

```
$ heroku info
=== jgodse-omniauth-mongoid
Web URL:        http://jgodse-omniauth-mongoid.heroku.com/
Git Repo:       git@heroku.com:jgodse-omniauth-mongoid.git
Dynos:          1
Workers:        0
Repo size:      7M
Slug size:      5M
Stack:          bamboo-mri-1.9.2
Data size:      (empty)
Addons:         Basic Logging, MongoHQ MongoHQ Free, Shared Database 5MB
Owner:          xxxxx@yyy.com

Jay@JAY-PC ~/rapps/rails3-mongoid-omniauth (master)
$ heroku config --long
BUNDLE_WITHOUT      => development:test
DATABASE_URL        => postgres://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com/rrretnhwhj
FACEBOOK_APP_ID     => xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET => xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
GITHUB_CLIENT_ID    => xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
GITHUB_SECRET       => xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
LANG                => en_US.UTF-8
MONGOHQ_URL         => mongodb://heroku:9xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.mongohq.com:27098/app527030
RACK_ENV            => production
SHARED_DATABASE_URL => postgres://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com/rrretnhwhj
TWITTER_KEY         => xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
TWITTER_SECRET      => xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

My github information for "OAuth Application: Jay's Rails3 Mongoid OAuth" is as follows (from my app profile page):

```
Authorization Token:   https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize
Access Token URL:      https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token
URL:     http://jgodse-omniauth-mongoid.heroku.com/
Callback URL:   http://jgodse-omniauth-mongoid.heroku.com/
Client ID: xxxxxxx
Secret:    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

The client and secret are set as environment variables in [omniauth.rb](https://github.com/jgodse/rails3-mongoid-omniauth/blob/bc52912411b9674b0f0efe1615dbaf7ecc02a000/config/initializers/omniauth.rb)

The authentication happens, but it redirects to http://jgodse-omniauth-mongoid.heroku.com/?error=redirect_uri_mismatch and I haven't apparently logged in. If I change the Callback URL to http://jgodse-omniauth-mongoid.heroku.com/callback, the application crashes.

What am I missing to get github authentication to work?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't fu%^&*g believe this.

I went to github.com where the application secret, key, url, callback is configured  and removed the trailing slash from the "Callback URL"  and "URL", and it worked.

```
URL: http://jgodse-omniauth-mongoid.heroku.com
Callback URL:  http://jgodse-omniauth-mongoid.heroku.com
```

This is nuts! Twitter wants the trailing slash on the callback but Github does not. Github and twitter should allow both and then trim it automatically if needed.

Comment: You just saved my evening & my sanity, sir!  Thanks!! :)

Comment: Indeed http://hueniverse.com/2012/07/26/oauth-2-0-and-the-road-to-hell/, "All the hard fought compromises on the mailing list, in meetings, in special design committees, and in back channels resulted in a specification that fails to deliver its two main goals – security and interoperability. In fact, one of the compromises was to rename it from a protocol to a framework, and another to add a disclaimer that warns that the specification is unlike to produce interoperable implementations."